# Elimination of this goto statement

Tags: c++, c

Was searching from ACM programming contest archives and found a solution to the coconuts program:
It has a goto in it- how do I eliminate this? Is there a template or procedure to follow to do so.
Thanks

```
/*
1997 East-Central ACM regional programming contest
Held on November 8, 1997
Coconuts, Revisited -- Problem 3
Sample solution by Ed Karrels, Ed@tool.com
November 1997
*/
#include <stdio.h>
/* return 1 if this number of coconuts can be divided up
properly between this number of people */
int SplitCoco(long n_coco, long n_people) {
long i;
for (i=0; i<n_people; i++) {
/* check that the coconuts divide by the number of people
plus one remainder */
    if (n_coco % n_people != 1) return 0;
    /* remove 1 for the monkey, and one person's share */
        n_coco = n_coco - 1 - (n_coco / n_people);
    }
    /* check that the remaining coconuts divide evenly among
    the people */
    return (n_coco % n_people) == 0;
}


int main() {
    long n_coco;
    long n_people;
    long i, j, k;

    FILE *inf = stdin;
    while (fscanf(inf, "%ld", &n_coco), n_coco!=-1) {
    /* starting at the # of coconuts-1, count down until
    a number of people is found that works */
        for (n_people=n_coco-1; n_people > 1; n_people--) {
            if (SplitCoco(n_coco, n_people)) {
                 printf("%ld coconuts, %ld people and 1 monkey\n",
                 n_coco, n_people);
                 goto found;
                 /* OK, so yea, I put a 'goto' in my code :-)
                it was quick and it works. I don't do
                it often, I swear. */
            }
        }
     /* if no number of people greater than 1 works, there is
     no solution */
        printf("%ld coconuts, no solution\n", n_coco);
        found:
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'd be a bit easier for us to read if you fixed your indentation.

Comment: Why remove the goto, mandated by company style or something?!

Comment: @Skurmedel http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Why should I keep it? I do not want to go the good vs. bad of goto. I now there are very few cases, according to some, that goto is Ok. I would just like to see if there was an algorithic way to remove.

Comment: Is the space bar broken? Or tab button?

Comment: .. If it ain't broke do not fix it.

Comment: This isn't even C :) In C a label can only be used to label a statement.

Comment: @Mysticial: Don't believe the hype. Why you should keep it, because it works? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you could make a separate routine countaining the `while` and replace the `goto found` with a `return`.

In general, you might replace each goto with a flag and some while loop. That does not make the code easier to read.

Comment: This is the clean way to do it! Don't use flags/booleans for this unless you really have to!

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
goto found;
```

with

```
 break;
```

replace

```
 printf("%ld coconuts, no solution\n", n_coco);
```

with:

```
if(n_people <= 1)
    printf("%ld coconuts, no solution\n", n_coco);
```

Comment: While this may work, I think it's often a bad pattern - it lends itself to off-by-one errors, and is fragile if the `for` loop might be reworked.

Comment: I actually like Basile Starynkevitch's first suggestion better (except with for instead of while). This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer has already suggested this but also suggested it was less readable - I disagree - I find it reads like what it means.  Either way like it or not it deserves illustrating as a possible solution.

My solution requires a definition of a boolean type.  I have assumed the the C99 `<stdbool.h>` definition (or C++ compilation)

This is just the body of the outer while loop:

```
    bool found = false ;
    for (n_people=n_coco-1; n_people > 1 && !found; n_people--) 
    {
        found = SplitCoco(n_coco, n_people)
        if( found ) 
        {
            printf("%ld coconuts, %ld people and 1 monkey\n", n_coco, n_people);
        }
    }

    if( !found ) 
    {
        /* if no number of people greater than 1 works, there is no solution */
        printf("%ld coconuts, no solution\n", n_coco);
    }
```

In some cases it is possible that the additional per-loop test is prohibitive, but I would suggest that in most cases it is insignificant.